# nUnit : Theory with Enum and ExpectedResult

Tags: c#, nunit

I am trying to put some cases to a method that I am writing test cases for.

```
bool SomeMethodName(EnumType enumvalue, bool someFlag)
```

There are 8 `EnumType` in my application,  this method only returns `true` with only two combinations of  `enumValue` and `someFlag`.

I am able to write `TestCase` for passed combination with `ExpectedResult` for all 8*2 combination of this method.

according to Doc https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Theory-Attribute

> For boolean and enum arguments, NUnit can supply the data without any action by the 
>   user. All possible values are supplied to the argument. This feature is disabled if the 
>   user supplies any values for the argument.

How I can use `ExpectedResult` with `Theory` attribute?

Comment: You can try to achieve it by using `Values` [attribute](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Values-Attribute) and `TestCase` Can you share more details about enum values and expected results?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, I can't figure it out `ExpectedResult` or something similar with `value`. Still with `value` i need to do `if{}..else{}` inside